# mongoose model, why do I need to use "new"? (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I don't understand this completely, as you will see.

But I create a new  mongoose.model like this:

```
let MyModel = moongoose.model<IMyModel>("myModel", MyModelSchema);
```

What is the diffrence on `MyModel` and `let newModel = new MyModel`?

I need to create `newModel`to use function such as `.save()`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `moongoose.model`, you're not creating an instance of your model, you're creating a constructor for it - in other words, `MyModel` is a class, and `newModel` is an instance of that class.